# Get AWS EMR Cluster ID from Name

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, groovy

AWS CLI command `aws emr list-clusters` returns the following json. Is there a way through bash or groovy that I can use the Name to get the Id? I can't just use the Id becauseI am deleting clusters and rebuilding them with only the same name. So I know the name of the cluster is "my-cluster" and I would like to use it somehow to get the Id of the cluster. End case is I actually want the Master public DNS of the cluster.

```
    {
        "Clusters": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "Timeline": {
                "ReadyDateTime": 1433200405.353,
                "CreationDateTime": 1433199926.596
            },
            "State": "WAITING",
            "StateChangeReason": {
                "Message": "Waiting after step completed"
                }
            },
            "NormalizedInstanceHours": 6,
            "Id": "j-3SD91U2E1L2QX",
            "Name": "my-cluster"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Timeline": {
                    "ReadyDateTime": 1433200405.353,
                    "CreationDateTime": 1433199926.596
            },
            "State": "WAITING",
            "StateChangeReason": {
                "Message": "Waiting after step completed"
            }
        },
        "NormalizedInstanceHours": 6,
        "Id": "j-3S281UEK8L2LW",
        "Name": "my-cluster2"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: your question asks how to get the cluster id, but you mention the end state is to get the public dns name for the cluster, do you want a 1-liner to get the dns name directly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `query` parameter to achieve what you are trying. The command will look like below:

```
aws emr list-clusters --query 'Clusters[?Name==`my-cluster`].Id' --output text
```

You can find the complete documentation for the `query` parameter [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter).

Comment: `list-clusters` will list all the clusters that the user have access to, isn't a time-consuming query?

Comment: it's good to note that if you have a lot of clusters hanging around, you should limit the number of clusters being processed by the cli cmd, by specifying for example the `--max-items` option

Comment: Following @DimitrisMoraitidis comment, it's also good to limit the range, e.g.:
--created-after 2022-05-15T00:01:30 --created-before 2022-05-21T00:01:30

Answer (score 1):

To answer the complete question, one could put the above approach into a long one-liner over several lines.

```
aws emr describe-cluster                                       \
 --output text                                                 \
 --cluster-id  $(aws emr list-clusters                         \
                  --active                                     \
                  --query 'Clusters[?Name==`my-cluster`].Id'   \
                  --output text)                               \
 --query Cluster.MasterPublicDnsName
```

Comment: How do you substitute `my-cluster` as a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID using `jq` bash command as follows

```
aws emr list-clusters --active | jq '.["Clusters"][0]["Id"]'
```

It will return the first active cluster Id as output